# What is alternative instead of view in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have below query and it isn't very important what the result is

```
SELECT
    `doctors`.`id` AS `id`,
    `doctors`.`name` AS `name`,
    count( `onvan-naghs`.`negative-mark` ) AS `negative_marks` 
FROM
    (
    (
    (
    ( `doctors` JOIN `doctor-barge-naghs` ON ( ( `doctor-barge-naghs`.`code-doctor` = `doctors`.`id` ) ) )
    JOIN `onvan-naghs` ON ( ( `doctor-barge-naghs`.`code-naghs` = `onvan-naghs`.`id` ) ) 
    )
    JOIN `barge` ON ( ( `doctor-barge-naghs`.`code-barge` = `barge`.`id` ) ) 
    )
    JOIN `paziresh` ON ( ( `barge`.`shomare-paziresh` = `paziresh`.`id` ) ) 
    ) 
WHERE
    ( `paziresh`.`tarikh_paziresh` BETWEEN 1111111111 AND 9999999999 ) 
GROUP BY
    `doctors`.`id`,
    `doctors`.`name` 
ORDER BY
    `onvan-naghs`.`negative-mark` DESC
```

then I save it as a view that  called  `scores`
then I use it in another query and it works well

```
SELECT
    `scores`.`id` AS `id`,
    `scores`.`name` AS `name`,
    `scores`.`negative_marks` AS `negative_marks`,
    find_in_set( `scores`.`negative_marks`, ( SELECT group_concat( DISTINCT `scores`.`negative_marks` ORDER BY `scores`.`negative_marks` DESC SEPARATOR ',' ) FROM `scores` ) ) AS `rank` 
FROM
    `scores`
```

but my problem is that I couldn't use a view in some situation
and I want to use an entire query and I have to use a sub-query
but I couldn't use a sub query outside it
like below

```
SELECT *,
    find_in_set( `t1`.`negative_marks`, ( SELECT group_concat( DISTINCT `t1`.`negative_marks` ORDER BY `t1`.`negative_marks` DESC SEPARATOR ',' ) FROM `t1` ) ) AS `rank` 
FROM
(
SELECT
    `doctors`.`id` AS `id`,
    `doctors`.`name` AS `name`,
    count( `onvan-naghs`.`negative-mark` ) AS `negative_marks` 
FROM
    (
    (
    (
    ( `doctors` JOIN `doctor-barge-naghs` ON ( ( `doctor-barge-naghs`.`code-doctor` = `doctors`.`id` ) ) )
    JOIN `onvan-naghs` ON ( ( `doctor-barge-naghs`.`code-naghs` = `onvan-naghs`.`id` ) ) 
    )
    JOIN `barge` ON ( ( `doctor-barge-naghs`.`code-barge` = `barge`.`id` ) ) 
    )
    JOIN `paziresh` ON ( ( `barge`.`shomare-paziresh` = `paziresh`.`id` ) ) 
    ) 
WHERE
    ( `paziresh`.`tarikh_paziresh` BETWEEN 1111111111 AND 9999999999 ) 
GROUP BY
    `doctors`.`id`,
    `doctors`.`name` 
ORDER BY
    `onvan-naghs`.`negative-mark` DESC
    ) as t1
```

It couldn't use t1 and understand what it is and say 'Table 'client-hospital.t1' doesn't exist'

What should I do  when I want to use an entire query instead of having  different views and sub-query couldn't be used outside?

I have tried using with syntax but it isn't supported in my platform
I need something  like below code

```
WITH
  cte1 AS (SELECT a, b FROM table1),
  cte2 AS (SELECT c, d FROM table2)
SELECT b, d FROM cte1 JOIN cte2
WHERE cte1.a = cte2.c;
```

and for example, imagine below picture
[an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B48EX.jpg)
why I couldn't use a sub-query this way if I find a way for this I think a get my answer

Comment: Including '-' in table/column identifiers is fantastically dangerous.

Comment: `FROM(find_in_set(` is not valid SQL.It's hard to tell exactly what your problem is but I'm pretty sure it's unrelated to your view. Perhaps if you could post the query with the view it might be easier to debug that.

Comment: It seems that you need the [common table expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) feature, which is new for MySQL (8.0).

Comment: yes exactly but my  MySQL version is MySQL 5.0.12-dev and I couldn't use it and couldn't upgrade it; I now use temporary tables but it has another problem that couldn't reopen more than once